# Which of these thermodynamic relationships is true for a system at equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

Which of the following is true at equilibrium

$$T \Delta{S} = \Delta{H}$$

$$T \Delta{s} = \Delta {G}$$

I think it's the first one but I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At equilibrium, $\Delta {G}$ is zero, so according to the equation $\Delta {G} = \Delta {H} - T \Delta {S}$ the first option is correct.